# HEAD is now at 9e52a21

Tags: kernel, git

I am trying to run a kernel module on a Nexus 7 emulator on Ubuntu.

I ran this command in the terminal: `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git`

Then I want to checkout this: `git checkout remotes/origin/android-msm-flo-3.4-jb-mr2`

Once I entered that line above I got this error:

```
HEAD is now at 9e52a21... 
qseecom: Fix issue with incomplete command exiting prematurely
```

I tried it with `sudo`, I tried adding things like `-p`, `-3` at the end of the command, but nothing works. How do I fix this?

Comment: When there is an error in git, normally it is louder than that. Nevertheless, it is a fair question ;)

Comment: For `sudo` you could use the `-E` option or `env_keep` to keep all the environment variables in place.

Comment: Close-voter(s): This is about Ubuntu; the question is about git (which is running directly on Ubuntu), not Android.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a commit message, and not an error. Your command succeeded.

Comment: The whole thing is git telling you what's been checked out: `HEAD` is git's term for 'the currently selected version', `9e52a21` identifies the particular version, and the following line is the commit message describing the most recent change.

Comment: @deltab +1 But, I believe it was specifically the commit message (qseecom: Fix issue with incomplete command exiting prematurely) that looked like an error to OP.

Comment: That is a consistent problem with Git: the output gives a lot of information, but you need a thorough understanding of Git to figure out whether it succeeded or failed.  This is a good example: after the checkout, it printed out the hash and the message of the latest commit.  Of course, the hash is unintelligible and many commit-message contain error messages (since they are typically fixing errors).

Comment: I like this idea.